# Inner product of a tensor product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Say we have a space $A$ and $B$ with a basis $|a_i>$ and $|b_i>$ on it. On the space $A \otimes B$, $|a_i> \otimes |b_j>$ is a basis vector. I am having difficulty understanding what happens when we take an inner product on this space. For example, 
$$
(<a_i| \otimes <b_j| )(|a_i> \otimes |b_j>) \overset{?}{=}  <a_i|a_i> \otimes <b_j |b_j>  $$

What does a tensor product of two numbers mean? Or more general the tensor product of a number with an vector in one of the spaces? This appears in the context of the partial trace.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces).

Comment: Wikipedia is enough. However,  from the *universality property* of the tensor product you see that $c\otimes {\bf v} = c{\bf v}$ and $c\otimes c' = c\cdot c'$ (where the identities are natural isomorphisms of vector spaces)... This sort of questions are however more appropriate for mathSE...

Comment: @ValterMoretti I have seen that but I don't see how the map is injective as $c \otimes c'$ and $c' \otimes c$ would both map to the same element of $\mathbb{R}$ presumably.

Comment: Universality says that the **bi-linear** map $f: {\mathbb R} \times {\mathbb R}\ni (c,c') \mapsto c\cdot c'\in \mathbb R$ uniquely "extends" (in the sense of univerality theorem) to a **linear** map $F: {\mathbb R}\otimes {\mathbb R} \mapsto \mathbb R$. This map is evidently surjective because its restriction $f$ is already surjective. Finally notice that ${\mathbb R}\otimes {\mathbb R}$ has dimension $1 \times 1 =1$ as a real vector space and $\mathbb R$ as dimension $1$ as well.

Comment: A **linear surjective** map from a finite dimensional vector space onto a finite dimensional vector space **with the same dimension** is necessarily **injective**. Therefore $F$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: As a matter of fact,  the universality theorem applied to this case says nothing but that the isomorphism $F: {\mathbb R}\otimes {\mathbb R} \mapsto \mathbb R$ is the unique linear extension of $c \otimes c' \mapsto c\cdot c'$ for every $c,c' \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: The case of the other natural isomorphism  $G : {\mathbb R}\otimes V \to V$, for a finite dimensional (here real) vector space $V$ (the infinite dimensional case requires some other hypotheses), can be handled similarly starting form the surjective bilinear map $g :  {\mathbb R}\times V\ni (c, {\bf v}) \mapsto c{\bf v}\in V$, observing that $V$ and ${\mathbb R}\otimes V$ have identical dimension.

Comment: Obviously, you are interested in the case of $\mathbb R$ replaced for $\mathbb C$. Nothing changes.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thank you. I've see my mistake (I think I have made it before)!